# <Div> Field Size

Tags: html, size

I wanted to know if there's any way by which one could restrict the size of a `<div>` field.

By this i mean if we keep altering the contents of `<div>`, is it possible for us to get a scrollbar within the div? Otherwise the size of the `<div>` expands uncontrollably and results in the page getting messy!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div#foo { width:500px; height:400px; overflow:auto; }
```